# Version of arch x64 not found

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

```
Run actions/setup-python@v1
  with:
    python-version: 2.7
    architecture: x64
Error: Version 2.7 with arch x64 not found
```

Available versions:

3.10.9 (x64)
3.11.1 (x64)
3.7.15 (x64)
3.8.15 (x64)
3.9.16 (x64)

I don't get which things to change to remove this issue and I am expecting , this 2.7 Version should be installed with x64 architecture.

Comment: Python 2.7 reached end of life a while ago, so don't expect it supported anywhere any more.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the comment, there was [`actions/runner-images` issues 810](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/810) which request support for Python 2.7 back in... 2020.

An pull request like [`actions/runner-images` PR 1705](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/pull/1705) illustrated in Sept. 2020 the new states:

> Currently, Python 2.7 is set by default on Ubuntu 20.04.   Python 2
> was sunsetted on Jan 1 2020 and this version is not supported anymore.
> In scope of this PR we set the default Python to 3.8 on Ubuntu 20.04.
>
> Alias: `bash /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3 ->  /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/pip -> /usr/bin/pip3`

So you would need to install it.